# Android lost focus handling in Vulkan

Tags: android, android-ndk, focus, vulkan, lost-focus

I'm playing with Vulkan in Android, whenever I touch `Overview button` (the one that is square) and get back to my app, it will crash.

#### Failed-Solution 1:

I tried to stop rendering When I loose focus and then resume rendering whenever I gain focus back, but It didn't work, I got crash at vkAcquireNextImageKHR.

#### Failed-Solution 2:

I tried to reinit all of the Vulkan objects from ground to up, but the sad funny thing is for the first loosing and gaining focus everything is OK but after twice, it crashes at the same point.

Comment: It should give you a lost device before crashing at the very least. Direct crashing is a bug IMO

Comment: Maybe you're right , maybe not, I'm not sure. But getting error on vkAcquireNextImageKHR is something meaningful, I'm still working on the other solution.

Comment: Are you using NativeActivity or mixed java/native code?

Comment: Does vkAcquireNextImageKHR really crash or does it just return a value that that tells you to recreate the surface (e.g. VK_ERROR_SURFACE_LOST_KHR)? If that happens you need to recreate the swapchain and all resources connected to it.

Comment: exactly! crash was a silly word, actually I got error. I've recreated swapchain and all of it related resoucres but it is still getting same error, I think, I missing some thing, Its need big chunk of time to trace it. I updated depth, stencil, render_pass, pileline (not the cache and layout) and draw commands.

Comment: What do you suggest in this kind of situation, I mean for tracing this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As hinted in my comment, check the result of vkAcquireNextImageKHR to determine if you need to recreate resources. If it's something like VK_ERROR_SURFACE_LOST_KHR you need to recreate the surface and all resources connected to it like the swap chain, etc. As a reference take a look at the [window resize function](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/base/vulkanexamplebase.cpp#L2029) of my example base class that is also called if vkAcquireNextImageKHR signals that the surface needs to be recreated.

As for error tracking (on what you actually need to recreate) enable the validation layers. Just put them along with the lib (.so) of your application, enable validation (note that you need to manually select all layers as there is no meta layer like VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation on android) and output validation messages to e.g. logcat. You can see my [debug unit as a reference](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/base/VulkanDebug.cpp).